# Extend matrix based on conditions in R

Tags: r, matrix

Consider the following random matrix:

`m <- cbind(c("r1","r2","r3","r4","r1","r2","r3","r4"),c(3,2,5,2,5,2,6,4))`

I want to extend it based on condition. For instance, how do I create an extra row under each row with the cell "r4", where the values are the exact same as in the rows with the cell "r4". Thus, then I will end up with the following matrix:

`m <- cbind(c("r1","r2","r3","r4","r4","r1","r2","r3","r4","r4"),c(3,2,5,2,2,5,2,6,4,4))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rep` to replicate each row which the cell `r4` like:

```
m[rep(seq_len(nrow(m)), 1 + (m[,1] == "r4")),]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "r1" "3" 
# [2,] "r2" "2" 
# [3,] "r3" "5" 
# [4,] "r4" "2" 
# [5,] "r4" "2" 
# [6,] "r1" "5" 
# [7,] "r2" "2" 
# [8,] "r3" "6" 
# [9,] "r4" "4" 
#[10,] "r4" "4"
```

`m[,1] == "r4"` gives a logical vector, where you can add 1 to tell `rep` how many times this row should be given.

Comment: Thanks! How do I add to rep if - for instance - I want to add 2 rows based on the condition that m[,1] == "r4"?

Comment: With `m[rep(seq_len(nrow(m)), 1 + 2*(m[,1] == "r4")),]`